# How to keep height of window always the same (Android Chrome Navigation Bar CSS Height)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create an UI for a browser game.

I have built the UI with layers where I split clickable content and background items (like the city images). I'm always using `height` with `%` units (no vh/vw). On desktop it's working fine however when I got to mobile (Chrome) and move the navbar the

- foreground layers orientate itself based on "height with navbar" (also initial here)
- background layers orientate itself based on the height of the current state of the navbar from Chrome

I'm trying to achieve that booth behave the same: Either update their height based on the navbar state or keep the height of the "height with navbar". So that the UI is not breaking...

[image: Preview]

Here is the current version: https://fix-issue-with-adblock-in-ch.more-or-less-frontend.pages.dev/game/largest-cities-in-the-united-states

I'm using TailwindCSS.

Comment: You may want to include some of your code, but if you need a fixed height, just explicitly set the height for mobile viewports, e.g. `md:h-[385px]`

Comment: @segFault It's a lot of code... I'll try to build a minimal reproductive example